# Show React code in Github Markdown

Tags: reactjs, github, markdown

I'm trying to create a React tutorial on Github, but I'm having issues with getting the Github formatting to line up with what I want to display. I would like to display this code:

````
```JavaScript
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <p className="App-intro">
          I'm a childish component
        </p>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```
````

But on Github, it is appearing like this:

[image]

Is the single quote the problem? Is Github unable to rend React because of the JavaScript/HTML mix?

Comment: That's **not** JavaScript. Try JSX.

Comment: https://andreypopp.github.io/reactdown/

Comment: you could also have added a \ backslash in front of the apostrophe to escape the character

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use JSX for the language:

````
```JSX
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class Child extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <p className="App-intro">
          I'm a childish component
        </p>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```
````

Should render correctly

Comment: Also `tsx` and `ts` for typescript

Comment: @Kewin Dousse I reverted your edit because this answer is meant to show the markdown ticks and language. It wouldn't help OP if it was just a formatted block of code.